# Append .tpl when loading partials/files in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

Let say that I load a partial in the template file, how can I automatically add the file extension, so when I do this

```
{include file='partials/head'}
```

it will actually do this:

```
{include file='partials/head.tpl'}
```

edit: in Mustache, I can do this:

```
'loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader('/resources/views', ['extension' => '.tpl.php'])
```

so it will append the file extension straightaway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modifying the engine itself, you can't.

Comment: Searching for the docs, and yup.. I settled it by modifying the engine